# apxs:Error: Command failed with rc=65536

Tags: mod-python, apxs2

Centos 6.4, WHM 11.38.1

I'm having trouble trying to make `mod_python` work.

I'm getting this error

```
apxs:Error: Command failed with rc=65536
```

I've already tried `custom_easyapache_modules`.
Also tried downloading the tar.gz and

```
./configure --with-apxs=/usr/local/apache/bin/apxs
make && make install
```

I also tried (https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=465246) to fix `/src/connobject.c`

Always the same message.

Answer (score 5):

https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/InstallationIssues

http://www.turnkeylinux.org/forum/support/20110502/compiling-apache-module-gives-apxserror-command-failed-rc65536

try recompiling your python with  --enable-shared'

Comment: How do I do this in virtual-env python?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me:

```
yum install python-devel
```

This was also a CentOS server (DirectAdmin, though).