# Cannot build mod_wsgi for python2.7 on Scientific Linux

Tags: python, linux, mod-wsgi

I have a web app developed with web.py using python 2.7.5.

I need to deploy it on a server running Scientific Linux 6.5. It comes with python 2.6.6 and the system requires this version, so I had to install python 2.7.5 in parallel.

What I need to do is to install mod_wsgi that uses python 2.7.5. I couldn't find a pre-compiled package, so I attempted to build one from source. I downloaded the source of mod_wsgi-3.4.

I ran configure with:

```
./configure --with-python=/home/mapto/Python-2.7.5/python
```

and got response:

> checking for apxs2... no
>
> checking for apxs... /usr/sbin/apxs
>
> checking Apache version... 2.2.15
>
> configure: creating ./config.status
>
> config.status: creating Makefile

When I run make it fails with:

> /usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a(abstract.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.8' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
>
> /usr/local/lib/libpython2.7.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
>
> collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>
> apxs:Error: Command failed with rc=65536
>
> .
>
> make: *** [mod_wsgi.la] Error 1

How can I sort out this problem? Would it help installing apxs2? If so, how can I do that? (apparently when I executed "yum install httpd-devel" it installed apxs, not apxs2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me: [apxs:Error: Command failed with rc=65536](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17996628/apxserror-command-failed-with-rc-65536)

I had to also do this, because of the parallel python versions: [Python executable not finding libpython shared library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880454/python-executable-not-finding-libpython-shared-library)